# Is There A USB Keyboard With A 9ft Cable?

Tags: usb, keyboards, cable

I have a computer connected to a TV that currently uses a wireless keyboard (Microsoft Wireless 3000 v2.0).

Generally it works fine for basic things like Netflix where there isn't much input, however, if I play games I often end up not being able to move in game.

This is either to do with batteries running out or some sort of interference (I'm not 100% sure).

Interestingly I don't have the same problems with the mouse.

I'd like to buy a keyboard with a long cable ~9ft so that I can plug it in and also be sitting reasonably far away from the TV.

It has to be a USB cable as I don't have a PS/2 port.

It needs to be a full size keyboard but it doesn't need an extra number pad.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to constrain yourself to keyboards with very long cable size instead of buying a usb extender cable? Is it that you are thinking of saving $? If you post a budget we can possibly recommend you a mechanical gaming keyboard with a usb extension setup (though this depends on your preferred keyboard type). Also it's worth mentioning that TV's typically have significantly slower response times than monitors which can greatly affect you in gaming scenarios where latency is important (etc. fps games).

Comment: I didn't even think about a usb extender cable. Its actually for a 7 year old to play minecraft so a very basic keyboard is fine.

Comment: So do you want recommendations for usb extender cables? Or do you want a keyboard recommendation along with it? If you want the keyboard recommendation you can just tell me a target price and preferred keyboard type (low/high profile, mechanical linear switch/membrane) and I can help you find the best quality keyboard at the price range.

Comment: I guess a recommendation for a cable and a basic ~78 key keyboard about 30cm wide or so. It would be nice to have some depth/traction to the keys and not be those super flat ones. Anything that looks cool to a 7-year old is a bonus! Less than $50 for the keyboard and cable would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard request you've put in sounds like you would like a *mechanical tenkeyless keyboard*. It sounds like you would dislike chiclet or membrane keyboards which are usually more low profile. Mechanical keyboards prevent ghosting keys, are usually a lot more sturdy, and have a much farther key travel distance than scissor switch membrane keyboards. Your request for looks cool to a 7-year old suggest you would like backlighting, and it is actually hard not to get keyboards lit up like a Christmas tree for mechanical keyboards at the price range.

### [USB 3.0 Extension Cable 10FT Type A Male to Female Extension $9.99](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZV6FHWF)

[image]

10 Ft Cable, and braided with aluminum for durability. Chances are with a cord this long in a common area with a TV someone is bound to snag something on it at some point. This should give you some piece of mind.

---

### [Velocifire Tenkeyless Mechanical Mini | $29.99](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071W16NVZ)

[image]

Keyboard that matches your request and has tactile feedback. Not a lot of reliable review data.

- 29.718 cm length
- Compact
- [Outemu Brown switch](https://mechanicalkeyboards.com/switches/index.php?switch=Outemu-Brown) mechanical

---

### [Redragon K552 Compact RGB Backlit | $39.99](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019O9BLVY)

[image]

- RGB blacklit with heavily customizable lighting patterns
- [Cherry MX Blue Switches](https://www.cherrymx.de/en/mx-original/mx-blue.html)
- Metal-ABS Construction
- **87** tenkeyless
- **35.4076 cm** length

First off, this keyboard is 87 tenkeyless and slightly over your 30 cm requirement. The reason I'm also recommending this keyboard is b/c it appears in several syndicated articles as a budget mechanical keyboard and has Cherry MX switches which I'm familiar with and are typing this recommendation with. Cherry MX is a household name for most casual and professional gamers.

Given my familiarity with the switches, reliable reviews I would consider this keyboard as well. Finally, you may want to play a racing game in the future and these typically lend themselves best to using the arrow keys, particularly if there is some sort of gear control on the cars.